# Workaround for Vim's inability to support `backupdir` full paths

Tags: vim

Recently I tried to switch to having backup and swap files in a directory other than the working directory. With swp files, you can just put double-slashes at the end of the path:

```
set directory=~/.vim/swp//
```

However, this does not work with `backupdir`. I found an answer with a workaround however:

```
autocmd BufWritePost * :execute ':w! ' ."$HOME/.vim/backups/" . escape(substitute(expand('%:p'), "/", "%", "g"), "%")
```

I have a few questions regarding this workaround:

- I know it saves files in `$HOME/.vim/backups/[filename with path]`, but **how** does it do this?
- How can I modify it so it saves the file as `%full%file%path%filename~` (the difference is the **~** at the end)
- Is it possible to reformat this command so it doesn't cross the preferred 80 char mark?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My workaround was

```
" this is a default. to be updated per file type
autocmd BufNewFile,BufNew,BufRead * let b:buDir = "/work/BACKUP/vimBackups/all/"
```

then later, on a per-file-type basis I did

```
let b:buDir = "/work/BACKUP/vimBackups/text/"
```

or

```
  let b:buDir = "/work/BACKUP/vimBackups/coding/"
```

Then, I call my backup on every exit

```
" the backup command
" currently, overwrite whatever is there: a new file will be made each second
" if necessary
autocmd VimLeavePre,BufWritePre * silent execute ":write! >> ".b:buDir."vim_bu_".strftime('%Y-%b-%d__%H:%M:%S')."_".b:buFilename.".bu.txt "
```

Then, in a daily clean-up script, run from cron (anacron), I delete out my old backups

```
# vim backups older than a month old
find $VIM_BU_DIR -not -newerat "1 month ago" -delete    ;
```

Comment: Definitely a very useful idea (and I marked it thus), but it doesn't quite fit what I need. I like the idea of storing the path name, and having all backups in one folder. Additionally, I have been requested not to install crontabs on this computer. Still though, neat idea!

Comment: OK, sure. You could not do the cron job, or not run anacron, but then over time your backups would build up: they will anyway; how will you clean out old backups? And by not customizing backups' directories on a per-file-type basis they would all go into one directory. But whatever works for you. Good luck.

Comment: I have been giving this some thought over the last short while, and your way is becoming more and more appealing. I have one question. Does the `let b:buDir = "..."` last between opening of files? Or do I need to do it each time I open the file?